# Автоматическое обновление layout экрана при открытии свёрнутого приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-layout

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть приложения, которому в состоянии открытия, закрытия и в свёрнутом состояние приходят сообщения, эти сообщения записываются в базу данных и выводятся на экран в списке RecyclerView. Но когда приложения находится в свёрнутом состояние добавления в список элемента не происходит, когда закрываем или сами пишем сообщение обновление экрана успешно происходит запись полученная в фоновом режиме успешно добавляется в RecyclerView.
Отсюда вопрос как можно обновлять layoyt экран когда открываем приложение после того как оно было свёрнуто, или данную проблему можно решить другим способом?

---

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnSend;
    EditText tvMessage;
    EditText tvNumber;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private static final String TAG="myLogs";

    public BroadcastReceiver intentReciever=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String telephone = "";
            String kluch="";
            String metka="";
            int shit=0;


            Log.i(TAG, "test color");
            String[][] myDataset = getDataSet();
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            // если мы уверены, что изменения в контенте не изменят размер layout-а RecyclerView
            // передаем параметр true - это увеличивает производительность
//            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            // используем linear layout manager
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
            mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            // создаем адаптер
            mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");

        btnSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        tvMessage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        tvNumber=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvNumber);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(mCorkyListener);


        String[][] myDataset = getDataSet();
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        // если мы уверены, что изменения в контенте не изменят размер layout-а RecyclerView
        // передаем параметр true - это увеличивает производительность
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // используем linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        // создаем адаптер
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
    private View.OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String myMsg=tvMessage.getText().toString();
            String theNumber=tvNumber.getText().toString();
            sendMsg(theNumber, myMsg);

            SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PHONE, theNumber);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH, myMsg);
            contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_MARCER, "i");
            database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);


            String[][] myDataset = getDataSet();

            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
            // если мы уверены, что изменения в контенте не изменят размер layout-а RecyclerView
            // передаем параметр true - это увеличивает производительность
//            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            // используем linear layout manager
            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            // создаем адаптер
            mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(myDataset);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }};

    private void sendMsg(String theNumber, String myMsg) {
        String SENT="Message Sent";
        String DELIVERED="Message Delivered";

        PendingIntent sentPI=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT),0);
        PendingIntent deliveredPI=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(DELIVERED),0);

        //myMsg-сообщение на отправку

        android.telephony.SmsManager sms= android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(theNumber, null, myMsg,sentPI,deliveredPI);


    }


    private String[][] getDataSet() {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int count=0;
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_ID);
            int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_PHONE);
            int keyIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH);
            int metkaIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_MARCER);
            do {
                count++;
                Log.i(TAG, "ID = " + cursor.getInt(idIndex) +
                        ", phone = " + cursor.getString(phoneIndex) +
                        ", key = " + cursor.getString(keyIndex)+
                        ", metka = " + cursor.getString(metkaIndex));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.i(TAG,"0 rows");
        cursor.close();

        Log.i(TAG, "размер базы равен "+count);

        String [][] phone_key_metka=new String[count][3];

        String telephone = "";
        String kluch="";
        String metka="";
        int shit=0;
        try {
                Cursor cursorrrr = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {"_id", DBHelper.KEY_PHONE}, null, new String[] {}, null, null, null);

                if (cursorrrr.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        int phone = cursorrrr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_PHONE);
                        telephone=cursorrrr.getString(phone);
                        Log.i(TAG,"______________ "+telephone);
                        phone_key_metka[shit][0]=telephone;
                        shit++;
                    } while (cursorrrr.moveToNext());
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG,"0 rows");}

                    shit=0;

                Cursor cursorrr = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {"_id", DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH}, null, new String[] {}, null, null, null);
                if (cursorrr.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        int key = cursorrr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH);
                        kluch=cursorrr.getString(key);
                        Log.i(TAG,"______________ "+kluch);
                        phone_key_metka[shit][1]=kluch;
                        shit++;
                    } while (cursorrr.moveToNext());
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG,"0 rows");}

                shit=0;

            Cursor table = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {"_id", DBHelper.KEY_MARCER}, null, new String[] {}, null, null, null);
            if (table.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int mera = table.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_MARCER);
                    metka=table.getString(mera);
                    Log.i(TAG,"______________ "+kluch);
                    phone_key_metka[shit][2]=metka;
                    shit++;
                } while (table.moveToNext());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG,"0 rows");}


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ошибка обработки массива");
        }


        Log.i(TAG, telephone);
        Log.i(TAG, kluch);

        for(int i=0; i<phone_key_metka.length; i++){
            Log.i(TAG, "phone "+phone_key_metka[i][0]);
            Log.i(TAG, "message "+phone_key_metka[i][1]);
            Log.i(TAG, "metka "+phone_key_metka[i][2]);
        }

        String[][] mDataSet = new String[count][2];
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (phone_key_metka[i][2].equals("me")){
                    mDataSet[i][0] = phone_key_metka[i][0]+" "+phone_key_metka[i][1];
                    mDataSet[i][1] = "";
                }else {
                    if (phone_key_metka[i][2].equals("i")){
                        mDataSet[i][0] ="";
                        mDataSet[i][1] = phone_key_metka[i][0]+" "+phone_key_metka[i][1];
                    } else{
                        mDataSet[i][0] ="";
                        mDataSet[i][1] = "";
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ошибка вывода на экран");
        }
        return mDataSet;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        registerReceiver(intentReciever, intentFilter);
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        unregisterReceiver(intentReciever);
        super.onPause();
    }

}
```

---

RecyclerAdapter.java (класс адаптера для RecyclerView)

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[][] mDataset;

    // класс view holder-а с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент
    // отдельного пункта списка
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // наш пункт состоит только из одного TextView
        public TextView leftView;
        public TextView rightView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            leftView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.leftSms);
            rightView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rightSms);
        }
    }

    // Конструктор
    public RecyclerAdapter(String[][] dataset) {

        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    // Создает новые views (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        // тут можно программно менять атрибуты лэйаута (size, margins, paddings и др.)

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Заменяет контент отдельного view (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.leftView.setText(mDataset[position][0]);
        holder.rightView.setText(mDataset[position][1]);

    }

    // Возвращает размер данных (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

---

MessageReceiver.java (класс для получения сообщений в том числе и в фоновом режиме)

```
public class MessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG="myLogs";
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        dbHelper=new DBHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] messages;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            messages = new SmsMessage[pdus != null ? pdus.length : 0];
            String phone="";
            String message="";
            for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) (pdus != null ? pdus[i] : null));
                //1-адресс приходс сообщения
                str += messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                str += ": ";
                //2-само сообщение
                str += messages[i].getMessageBody();
                str += "\n";

                phone=messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                message=messages[i].getMessageBody();
                Cursor cur = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {"_id", DBHelper.KEY_PHONE}, null, new String[] {}, null, null, null);
                boolean k=cur.moveToFirst();

                if (k==false) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "база пуста");

                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PHONE, phone);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH, message);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_MARCER, "me");
                    database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);



                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", str);
                    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                } else  {
                    Log.i(TAG, "базза не пуста");
//                    database.delete(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, DBHelper.KEY_ID, null);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_PHONE, phone);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_KLUCH, message);
                    contentValues.put(DBHelper.KEY_MARCER, "me");
                    database.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_CONTACTS, null, contentValues);



                    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                    broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                    broadcastIntent.putExtra("message", str);
                    context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            abortBroadcast();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: в колбэке onResume() пропишите логику обновления. Этот метод вызывается, когда активити выходит из фона. И обновлять вам нужно не Layout, а данные в адаптере, если речь идет о списке (метод `notifyDataSetChanged()` адаптера и аналогичные, в зависимости от задач)

Comment: спасибо помогло)